# Friction factor by Blasius equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am confused by 2 expressions I am getting regarding Blasius equation for darcy friction factor:-

f = 0.079/Re^0.25 
and
f = 0.316/Re^0.25

Can any one help me out

Answer (score 2):

One of these is the Fanning friction factor and the other is the Darcy Weisbach friction factor.  The Fanning friction factor is 1/4 the Darcy Weisbach friction factor.

If you are calculating the pressure drop for flow of an incompressible fluid in a pipe in terms of the Fanning friction factor, then you are using the equation: $$\Delta P=\left(\frac{4L}{D}\right)\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 f_F$$

If you are calculating the pressure drop for flow of an incompressible fluid in a pipe in terms of the Darcy Weisbach friction factor, then you are using the equation: $$\Delta P=\left(\frac{L}{D}\right)\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 f_{DW}$$

So the two representations are entirely equivalent.